# Why COALESCE within a subquery returns NULL?

Tags: sql-server

Given this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST_COALESCE
(
    Id int NOT NULL,
    DateTest datetime NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id, DateTest)
);

INSERT INTO #TEST_COALESCE VALUES
(1, '20170201'),
(1, '20170202'),
(1, '20170203'),
(2, '20170204'),
(2, '20170205'),
(2, '20170206');
```

If I use COALESCE within a subquery, it returns NULL.

```
SELECT  t1.Id, t1.DateTest,
        (SELECT TOP 1 COALESCE(t2.DateTest, t1.DateTest)
         FROM         #TEST_COALESCE t2
         WHERE        t2.Id = t1.Id
         AND          t2.DateTest > t1.DateTest
         ORDER BY     t2.Id, t2.DateTest) NextDate
FROM    #TEST_COALESCE t1;

+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| Id | DateTest            | NextDate            |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1  | 01.02.2017 00:00:00 | 02.02.2017 00:00:00 |
| 1  | 02.02.2017 00:00:00 | 03.02.2017 00:00:00 |
| 1  | 03.02.2017 00:00:00 | NULL                |
| 2  | 04.02.2017 00:00:00 | 05.02.2017 00:00:00 |
| 2  | 05.02.2017 00:00:00 | 06.02.2017 00:00:00 |
| 2  | 06.02.2017 00:00:00 | NULL                |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
```

However, if it is placed outside the subquery:

```
SELECT  t1.Id, t1.DateTest,
        COALESCE((SELECT TOP 1 t2.DateTest
                 FROM         #TEST_COALESCE t2
                 WHERE        t2.Id = t1.Id
                 AND          t2.DateTest > t1.DateTest
                 ORDER BY     t2.Id, t2.DateTest), t1.DateTest) NextDate
FROM    #TEST_COALESCE t1;

+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| Id | DateTest            | NextDate            |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1  | 01.02.2017 00:00:00 | 02.02.2017 00:00:00 |
| 1  | 02.02.2017 00:00:00 | 03.02.2017 00:00:00 |
| 1  | 03.02.2017 00:00:00 | 03.02.2017 00:00:00 |
| 2  | 04.02.2017 00:00:00 | 05.02.2017 00:00:00 |
| 2  | 05.02.2017 00:00:00 | 06.02.2017 00:00:00 |
| 2  | 06.02.2017 00:00:00 | 06.02.2017 00:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Why the first subquery does not return: `t1.DateTest`?

http://rextester.com/CNDOO40877

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Things in the select are returned only if there are rows returned in the FROM statement.

**First, let's think of it conceptually.**

Query 1 is like:

> "Go find all of the Ferraris in your garage. For each Ferrari, give me
>   the license plate number, or if it doesn't have a plate number, give
>   me 'NO FERRARIS FOUND.'"

The query would come back with no rows - because there wasn't a Ferrari in the garage. (At least, there weren't any rows found in my own garage.)

Query 2 is different:

> "Go to the garage. IF you find a license plate on a Ferrari, give me
>   that - otherwise, give me 'NO FERRARIS FOUND.'"

That's why the coalesce has to be outside of the search operation: you need it to happen even when there's no rows in the result set.

**Now, let's look at your query.**

I'm going to take the subquery out on its own, and I'm going to hard-code values for one of the rows where you want the COALESCE to work, but it can't:

```
SELECT TOP 1 COALESCE(t2.DateTest, 'NO FERRARIS FOUND')
     FROM         #TEST_COALESCE t2
     WHERE        t2.Id = 1
     AND          t2.DateTest > '2017-02-03 00:00:00.000'
     ORDER BY     t2.Id, t2.DateTest
```

In the WHERE clause, I've hard-coded Id = 1 and DateTest > '2017-02-03 00:00:00.000'. When this query runs, it returns no results:

[image: No Ferraris found]

That's why the COALESCE doesn't work: there were no rows in this result set, and no Ferraris in your garage. Master that concept, and you will have Ferraris in your...wait a minute...I've mastered that concept, and there are no Ferraris in my garage...